# Joda Interval losing timezone information

Tags: java, jodatime

I am defining a Joda interval as follows:

```
final DateTimeZone fromDtz = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris");
final DateTime fromDt = DateTime.parse("2013-08-08T01:02:03+0200").withZone(fromDtz);
final DateTimeZone toDtz = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
final DateTime toDt = DateTime.parse("2013-08-08T01:02:05+0100").withZone(toDtz);
final Interval interval = new Interval(fromDt, toDt);
```

However it appears that I lose the information on the timezone for the end of the interval.  If I do a simple `toString()` on the interval I receive:

```
2013-08-08T01:02:03.000+02:00/2013-08-08T02:02:05.000+02:00
```

which is missing some of the information I'm trying to retain (the specific timezone of the datetime at the end of the interval).

I've wandered through the documentation and source code and it appears that `Interval` only contains a single chronology.  Is there a way to tell Joda to keep both timezones without manually carting around two separate `DateTime`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally an interval is the time between two *instants* - and instants don't have chronologies, time zones etc. They're just points on a universal time line - a number of milliseconds since an epoch. The fact that `ReadableInterval` exposes `getChronology` at all is a design flaw, IMO - but there really is only *one* such chronology. If you're trying to keep more information than that, I believe you'll need to use your own type.

It may be as simple as a start/end pair and a `toInterval()` method for places where you really want to use the Joda Time `Interval` methods, but I don't think there's anything built into Joda Time to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, although I can see why they would want to have a chronology as otherwise I'm not sure how methods like `toString()` would be able to print anything sensible, and given that it seems unfair not to expose it.  Guess I'll continue to roll my own.  Thanks!

Comment: @jgm: ToString should just use the ISO chronology, IMO. That's what we do in Noda Time. It's fundamentally *not* part of the interval, as described by "a pair of instants". While the Joda Time API is certainly vastly better than Date and Calendar, it still has some ugly warts :(

Comment: True, and given that JSR-310 doesn't even have `Interval` (`InstantInterval` was removed a while back) I suppose that building my own won't hurt.

Answer (score -1):

try using `withZoneRetainFields()`

Comment: The problem is that the interval itself only stores a single chronology, and the OP wants to maintain two.

Comment: 'fraid that isn't the issue.  My problem is not around the fact that the dates are in the wrong zone; each of `fromDtz` and `toDtz` are consistent in that respect.  The issue is that `Interval` only remembers a single chronology.